# Python Syntax for loop output

Tags: python

What does this code do?  I understand it is running a for loop, checking each array element for nulls.  I don't understand why there are 2 functions: isnull & any.  Also, what does the col before the 'for' do?  It looks like a for loop can return the iterable and a tuple is being made.  Is that in the Python docs?

```
cols_with_missing = [col for col in X_train.columns
                         if X_train[col].isnull().any()]
```

Comment: You could manually explore what this does. Instead of  `col for col in X_train.columns` inside the list-comprehension, just pick any column name e.g. 'B'.  Then see for yourself what `X_train['B'].isnull()` returns.

Comment: Whle list comprehensions are a core Python feature, data frames are not. The question is basically too broad (three questions in one) and a reader will have to guess several things right to properly understand it (and a title which seems to be vaguely about something else doesn't help either). I hope the selected duplicate will help you solve your problem; if not, you should probably spend some time in the [help] before trying to articulate a better question. Also note that Pandas generally prefers vectorized operations over list-based approaches.

Comment: ```[col for col in X_train.columns ... ]```  -  This is Python and it is list comprehension.  A way of generating a new list from another list or some kind of collection of items.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary:** It returns a `list` of column names which have missing values.

**Explanation:**

- `X_train[col].isnull()`: returns a [`series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) of True, False values.
- `X_train[col].isnull().any()`: returns a scalar value i.e. True or False